# JAXB unmarshalling exception: unexpected element when spring webservice 1.0.4

Tags: spring, spring-ws, jaxb2

I have written spring webservice cleint example This is working fine with springws1.5 but when running with spring ws 1.0.4 i am getting below exception. Please help me why we will get this exception and how to resolve. I need to use down version only as my spring version is 2.0.4. Please reply as soon as possible.

```
Unhandled exception: 
    org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.JaxbUnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception: unexpected element (uri:"http://yyy.org", local:"xxxResponse"). Expected elements are <{}xxx>,<{}xxxResponse>; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"yyy.org", local:"xxxResponse"). Expected elements are <{}xxx>,<{}xxxResponse>
    Caused by: 
    javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://yyy.org", local:"xxxResponse"). Expected elements are <{}xxx>,<{}xxxResponse>
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:603)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:244)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:239)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:116)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1009)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:446)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:427)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:71)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:240)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:123)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:314)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:297)
     at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:107)
     at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:395)
     at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.unmarshal(MarshallingUtils.java:62)
     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$2.extractData(WebServiceTemplate.java:276)
     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:417)
     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:265)
     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:253)
     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:245)
     at encompass.mtm.webservices.Code1ServiceClient.getAddressCheckResponse(Code1ServiceClient.java:24)
```

I have coded using following example
http://justcompiled.blogspot.com/2010/11/web-service-client-with-spring-ws.html
*The following changes i have done:*
Genereate classes using `wsconsume` batch file from jboss bin,
I have kept jars

```
saaj1.3.jar, spring-ws-core-1.0.4.jar,spring-xml-1.0.4.jar
spring-oxm-tiger-1.0.4.jar,spring-oxm-1.0.4.jar
```

in `jboss/../lib`

Following is in my spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
        <property name="messageFactory">
            <bean class="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="test1ObjectFactory" class="test.webservices.ObjectFactory"/>
    <bean id="test1ServiceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="test.webservices" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="test1ServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="test1ServiceMarshaller"></property>
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="test1ServiceMarshaller"></property>
        <property name="messageSender">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultUri" value="${webservice.url}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="test1ServiceClient" class="test.webservices.test1ServiceClient">
        <constructor-arg ref="test1ServiceTemplate"></constructor-arg>
        <property name="test1ObjectFactory" ref="test1ObjectFactory"></property>
    </bean>
```

Now i have replaced everything and place `webservice 1.5.0 jar`. Stil i am facing this problem, Previously it worked. I haven't done much chanegs. is any thing disturbed in my code? How to chesk ..How to track this. Any help is highly appreciated.
My ObjectFactory is simple:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: test.webservices
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link xxxResponse }
     * 
     */
    public XxxResponse createxxxResponse() {
        return new xxxResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link xxx }
     * 
     */
    public Xxx createXXX() {
        return new XXX();
    }
```

}

Input
Following are classlevel annotations

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "xxxData"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Xxx")
```

Response:

```
  @ XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "xxxResult"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "XxxResponse")
```

Comment: Please give me reply when we get this error. Where to look at?

Comment: Please suggest me how to keep logs and how to resolve these errors?

Comment: No one is answering?? Need some more information or this question is not clear. Please help me i am really looking for this.

Comment: I have added configuration file in my question, Please help me out.I am working on couple of days and getting all type of errors please do me favour.

Comment: No replies from yesterday. I am really looking for this. Please help me

Comment: Noone else is reading these comments apart from you, you know :)

Comment: What else i need to do? Normally i will get reply asap when i post the question. What about this? May be so many are working on this webservices. I am trying to solve this but not able to and trying on net. Thatswhy i am keeping comments..and looking for help

Comment: Maybe noone knows the answer. Spring-WS isn't a popular framework (although it deserves to be).

Comment: Can we see the contents of the `jaxb.properties`, `package-info.java` and `ObjectFactory.java` from the `test.webservices` package, if they exist?

Comment: I dont have jaxb.properties. I didn't keep package-info.java in my structure. Is it required? I have posted ObjectFactory.java. There xxx is masked for AddrCheck. Thank you for ur time

Comment: OK, this is all helping. What class-level annotations do you have on `AddrCheck` and `AddrCheckResponse`?

Comment: I have added annotations for these classes in my Question Thank u.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exception you're getting is telling you that the JAXB context is expecting to receive elements with no XML namespace. It's expecting this because your JAXB-annotated classes do not have a namespace defined anywhere. You'd expect to find this declared as `@XmlNamespace`, somewhere in the bound classes (or in `package-info.java`), but you don't have that anywhere.

Spring-WS, however, is receiving responses that *do* have a namespace (the `http://yyy.org` in your example), and so the unmarshalling fails.

What I can't explain is how this ever worked with Spring-WS 1.5.x - the namespace mismatch should fail for every version.

Whatever tool you used to generate the JAXB classes *should* have produced a `package-info.java` file that declared the namespace. Are you sure it's not in there somewhere?

Comment: Thank you sir. This is really my bad. I didnt know that this package-info.java is that important. I didn't keep this file thinking that it contain only package name.Now i kept and every thing worked correctly. By searching google, i tried to keep namespace for AddrCheck and AddrCheckResponse files in XmlRootElement. But that time i got null result. Any way thank you so much sir. Thatswhy i kept one more question to understand how these marshaller works, Any way thank you very much sir again.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but i never deleted the package-info.java file and double checked if it is really there too. Could you give me some hints please?

Comment: I have kept package-info.java in place but still I get unexpected element error. Any idea what else I am missing?